# I want to make a blueprint for for spawning the same character each with a diffrent value of morph targets

Tags: character, spawn, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

When I try to spawn the character class from another blueprint, isntances of of the character is created in diffrent location, but every character keeps changing its morph target values each second, and also all the instances change the values at the same time.

I want to make a blueprint for spawning the same character each with a different value of morph targets in different locations. The character clothing parts, need to be included as well; the clothes have morph targets as well.

Here is the progress I made:

1. I was able to create a seed value that randomly changes the values of the morph target of the character and its shirt accordingly.
   [Seed Value for changing Morph Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XLhX.jpg)
2. I put an event trigger tick to randomize the values of the morph target each second.
   [Randomize morph target with time- 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZj2K.jpg)
   [Randomize morph target with time- 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lclrw.jpg)
3. Now when I try to spawn my character class from another blueprint, it changes the values of each morph target. But each isntances together. Even tried making a custom event for the trigger but wasn't of much help.
   [Trying to spawn instances of the character each with unique values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPcxo.jpg)

The blueprint makes an instance of itself each time, and I am unable to change the value of only the instance when it is being spawned. I am new to blueprint or programming altogether.

How do I achieve this?

(Also I couldn't share the videos along with the images here, you can find the videos here: [text](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/i-want-to-make-a-blueprint-for-for-spawning-the-same-character-each-with-a-diffrent-value-of-morph-targets/1171162)